# Дизайн кнопки с помощью СSS

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать такой дизайн кнопки с помощью CSS или только можно с наложением `background`?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опишите словами, что значит «такой дизайн», чтобы и вопрос стал понятнее, и в поисковиках он проиндексировался лучше (вопросы с одними лишь картинками плохо ищутся и бесполезны для базы знаний)

Comment: Я имею в виду, чтобы был не просто розовый фон, а с "лучами", выходящими из правого верхнего угла. То есть я не представляю как можно такое организовать с помощью CSS)

Comment: вот зафотошопил чуть чуть  [вариант](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/REXmYe) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это самое крутое что я смог выдумать :

```css
button {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button span {
  position: relative;
}

button:before {
  content: "";
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: tomato;
  background-image: conic-gradient(red 240deg, red 260deg, transparent 260deg, transparent 280deg, red 280deg, red 300deg, transparent 300deg, transparent 320deg, red 320deg, red 340deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>какая то кнопка</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно подобное реализовать на CSS, отдалено похожий пример:

```css
div {
  width: 80vmin;
  height: 80vmin;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: linear-gradient(#f90, #95a);
  -webkit-mask: repeating-conic-gradient(#000 0% 2.5%, transparent 0% 5%);
  mask: repeating-conic-gradient(#000 0% 2.5%, transparent 0% 5%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```